# Put each object with same name into single dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, object, tuples

I have following list of dictionaries:

```
[{'id': '1'},
 {'name': 'test'},
 {'email': 'test@gmail.com'},
 {'id': '2'},
 {'name': 'supra'},
 {'email': 'supra@gmail.com'},
 {'id': '3'},
 {'name': 'gtr'},
 {'email': 'gtr@gmail.com'}]
```

What i want is the following:

```
data_list = [{"id":"1", "name":"test", "email":"test@gmail.com"},
             {"id":"2", "name":"supra", "email":"supra@gmail.com"},
             ...]
```

What i have tried:

```
v = [{k: v for d in data_list for k, v in d.items()}]
```

But the above code updates only the last object cause of same key name.

Any idea how to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `d` is consistent, you can use the following (hacky) solution to iterate by the groups of 3:

```
ids = names = emails = iter(d)
data_list = [
    {
        'id': i['id'],
        'name': n['name'],
        'email': e['email']
    } for i, n, e in zip(ids, names, emails)
]
```

result:

```
[{'id': '1', 'name': 'test', 'email': 'test@gmail.com'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'supra', 'email': 'supra@gmail.com'}, {'id': '3', 'name': 'gtr', 'email': 'gtr@gmail.com'}]
```

And even simpler (suggested by @fsimonjetz) and my favorite one:

```
ids = names = emails = iter(d)
data_list = [i | n | e for i, n, e in zip(ids, names, emails)]
```

Comment: That's cool! `i|n|e` is another option to combine the dictionaries inline.

Answer (score 2):

Using simple list + dictionary comprehensions with [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) slicing:

```
N = 3
out = [{k:v for d in data_list[i:i+N] for k,v in d.items()}
       for i in range(0, len(data_list), N)]
```

This makes it easy to generalize to any `N`.

Variant (not faster):

```
from collections import ChainMap

N = 3
out = [dict(ChainMap(*data_list[i:i+N])) for i in range(0, len(data_list), N)]
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '1', 'name': 'test', 'email': 'test@gmail.com'},
 {'id': '2', 'name': 'supra', 'email': 'supra@gmail.com'},
 {'id': '3', 'name': 'gtr', 'email': 'gtr@gmail.com'}]
```

Used input:

```
data_list = [{'id': '1'},
             {'name': 'test'},
             {'email': 'test@gmail.com'},
             {'id': '2'},
             {'name': 'supra'},
             {'email': 'supra@gmail.com'},
             {'id': '3'},
             {'name': 'gtr'},
             {'email': 'gtr@gmail.com'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your input list is guaranteed to be arranged in groups of three then:

```
_list = [
    {
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "test"
    },
    {
        "email": "test@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "id": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "supra"
    },
    {
        "email": "supra@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "id": "3"
    },
    {
        "name": "gtr"
    },
    {
        "email": "gtr@gmail.com"
    }
]

data_list = []

for i in range(0, len(_list), 3):
    data_list.append(_list[i] | _list[i+1] | _list[i+2])

print(data_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': '1', 'name': 'test', 'email': 'test@gmail.com'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'supra', 'email': 'supra@gmail.com'}, {'id': '3', 'name': 'gtr', 'email': 'gtr@gmail.com'}]
```